# Problem with shared folder SAS University Edition on a Mac using Parallels Desktop

Tags: macos, sas, centos, virtual-machine, parallels

I've managed to install the SAS University Edition (SASUE) as a VM on Parallels Desktop 14.  The appliance works, but the shared folder is not showing up.  I managed to install the Parallel Tools onto the SASUE image by starting the image in recovery mode and making some "interesting" edits, then running the Parallels Tools installer.  The settings in Parallels show the shared folder, but still no luck when I start up SASUE.

I used the following guides as a starting point.

- [Using SAS University Edition in Batch Mode](https://ben.artins.org/software/sas-university-edition-batch-mode/)
- [Parallels Community forum Post](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/cant-install-parallels-tools-on-centos-7-1804.344573/) (See ErlingJ's reply to the OP)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use Oracle VirtualBox? It's freen, been tested and verified on it and works fine. I use it with VMWare with no issues on a Mac desktop.

Comment: Assuming the last post in [this thread](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Analytics-U/Install-SAS-University-Edition-in-Parallels-Desktop/td-p/169647) is you, that's the place to post this question I'd say; but as the answer to the original question went, this is not a supported option, and probably won't be.

Answer (score 0):

So I just went with Virtualbox. I was Leary of installing it alongside Parallels, but haven’t had any problems other than to poor resource optimization with VirtualBox. I really like Parallels, but oh well! It’s a shame they don’t (and maybe won’t support it). That’s life.